# Win 10 doesn't properly handle video after upg from Win 7 (AMD Firepro 2460)

Tags: windows-10, amd-graphics-card

Immediately after updating from Win 7, the resolution of my main monitor (a 30" Dell 3007WFP) was detected correctly, AND it displayed correctly.

However, after installing the latest win 10 kit for this AMD board (from the AMD driver download area), the needed modes are missing. (See shot below)

What would next step be?

(Note: Everything is electrically hooked up correctly: dual link cable, etc. -- this exact rig of monitor and cables has been used successfully for full resolution)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test it myself, but I found this:

> Requirements for high resolution display devices:
>
> If the required resolution is 2560x1600 pixels (such as running on a 30” display), the following conditions must be met:
>
> - The monitor and graphics card must be connected with a Dual-Link DVI cable.
> - The graphics card must have a Dual-Link DVI port.
>
> Note! If these requirements are not met, the maximum resolution will be limited to 1280 x 800.
>
> **Reference**: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/GPU-10-SupportedResolutionsUnavailableforMonitor.aspx

Comment: Yes, thank you. Not applicable. OP enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the problem was really frustrating. The monitor was correctly configured after the initial upgrade to win 10 (and an extra reboot or two). The problem began after installing the latest Firepro kit from the AMD web site (which did not update the driver itself from what I can tell, but did install the AMD control center).

As I planned on going to a new video board (to support high dpi displays), I just went forward and replaced the FirePro with an nvidia NVS 510. Once the nvidia drivers were installed, the correct displays were detected and it all just worked.